# Как вывести изображения из галереи текущего товара в превью его карточки?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите пожалуйста, как вывести изображения из галереи текущего товара (.product) на страницу каталога (.products) в виде превью всех изображений?
В данный момент на странице каталога получается вывести изображения только для первого товара.

Буду благодарен за любую информацию.

```
    add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'add_custom_flipper_img', 30);

function add_custom_flipper_img() {
    global $product;
    $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();
    
    foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'thumbnail');
    }
}
```